# Do I need to install MySQL Server on client machine, the database is used (Read, Write, Delete) by Python script I wrote?

Tags: python, mysql

I have written a python script that uses the MySQL Connector for Python to read, write and update the database. Do I need to install MySQL server on the client machine (Windows) too to run the program or do I just need to make sure that the database is present in the path used by the script? I tried finding guidance on Google and here but couldn't find what I needed.

Comment: When you connect to the database you specify the name or ip address of the database server, for example `conn  = mysql.connector.connect(host='10.10.0.101', user=...)`.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need to install MySQL Server on a client machine. By definition client machine means you don't have the DB/Server there. Where is this DB allocated? You show have an IP or a domain/subdomain address where the DB is actually hosted.